# What is changing my $PATH?

Tags: terminal, path, zsh

When I open a new Terminal, the $PATH is not what I set in .zshenv

`grep -i path .??*` shows that no other dot-file sets the path.

Adding a couple of `echo`, I see:

```
Last login: Thu Nov 18 13:29:13 on ttys000
PATH: /usr/bin:/bin
path: /usr/bin /bin
WGroleau@MBP ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/WGroleau/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/WGroleau/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
WGroleau@MBP ~ % cat .zshenv
echo "PATH: $PATH"
echo "path: $path"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1
export PATH=~/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
WGroleau@MBP ~ %
```

/Library/Apple/usr/bin doesn't even exist!  From the comment, I guess it's something Apple removed in 12.0.1

Comment: RE: "/Library/Apple/usr/bin doesn't even exist!" --  What version of **macOS** are you running?  I'm asking because it exists on my system running **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your .zshenv, so it'll print what's happening in the init files and you can see where the additions are taking place.

Comment: What is in /Library/Apple/usr/bin ?  Maybe it's a bug that Apple moved it and failed to change whatever puts it on the path.

Answer (score -3):

From Gordon's comment, I found two disconcerting things:

1. -x shows about a hundred actions for EVERY command entered.
2. /etc/zprofile is called AFTER the user's .zshenv to change the path using a compiled executable in /usr/libexec/path_helper, which overrides ~/.zshenv by reading files /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/*

So, no telling whether it's an Apple bug or whether some third party screw-up did it.  The man page does say that I can override the damage in ~/.zprofile